# Self-encrypting drive - eDrive vs ATA Security

Tags: disk-encryption, hardware, ssd

Let's for a moment forget about the possible drawbacks of SEDs themselves. One of the upsides of SEDs is that the encryption key never leaves the drive but wouldn't using eDrive negate this advantage because the key is also stored in the TPM and can be accessed on Windows?

[image]

If I'm able to back up the encryption key on Windows, malware should possibly be able to do so as well and on that basis SED over ATA-Security should be safer, right?

Comment: Note that you or a malware can't simply get access to the Bitlocker recovery key. Access to that feature is enforced by windows UAC, this is depicted on your screenshot with the shield icon.

Comment: If Windows allows you to backup the recovery key the volume is unlocked so malware could simply access the data directly. Malware is usually acting remotely performing an online attack. Bitlocker however protects against offline attacks.